# Incomplete type is not allowed (pointer)

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have a college problem that asks the following (The struct is already given by the teacher):

"Write a function void readDate(Date *d) that reads a date from the keyboard, in the format year/month/day. For simplicity, consider that the user always inputs a valid date."

The question itself is easy, what I don't understand is why the function is giving an error(line 7 - "incomplete type is not allowed" and "identifier d is undifined", and I don't understand if it was the teacher's mistake or mine since the "void readDate(Date *d)" was given by him.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct  Date{
    unsigned int year, month, day;
} Date;

void readDate( Date* d) {
    string date;
    size_t index;
    getline(cin, date); //for simplicity, user input is considered to be always valid
    d->year = stoi(date.substr(0, 3));
    d->month = stoi(date.substr(5, 6));
    d->day = stoi(date.substr(8, 9));
}

int main()
{
    struct Date* ptr = &Date;
    realDate(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: use a different name for the object `Date` than the type `Date`

Comment: ... or else write `struct Date` everywhere you mean the type, and plain `Date` where you mean the object (if, for some reason, you cannot change them to have different names).

Comment: @Luís: There are two answers provided to this question. If any of them answer your question to your satisfaction, please remember to accept that answer. Otherwise, consider leaving a comment on the answers to help provide feedback as to why the answer is not accepted. (I don't normally comment on this, but I've noticed from your post history that questions don't appear to have accepted answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current code:

```cpp
struct  Date{ // (1)
    unsigned int year, month, day;
} Date; // (2)
```

Creates a structure (type) named `Date` at (1), and an instance of that structure also named `Date` at (2). The instance of the structure will *shadow* the type with the same name, which is what is causing this issue.

From the looks of it, you don't actually need the `Date` instance to be globally defined. You should be able to move the instance into `main`, which changes this to simply be:

```cpp
struct Date{
    unsigned int year, month, day;
};

...

int main()
{
    Date date;
    Date* ptr = &date; // you can even avoid this step, and just do readDate(&date) directly
    readDate(ptr);
    ...
}
```

Otherwise, the code of:

```cpp
void readDate(Date* d) {
```

will treat the identifier `Date` as an instance of type `Date`, but not as the type `Date` itself -- which leads to confusing errors like you are experiencing.

If the `Date` instance needs to be defined globally, then ideally you should give it a name that is different than the type (such as `struct Date { ... } date;)`. If this is not possible, you will have to prefix all uses of the *type* with `struct` to disambiguate it, like:

```cpp
void readDate(struct Date* d) {
```

---

If the prof gave you code that has:

```
struct Date {
    ...
} Date;

void readDate(Date* d) {
    ...
}
```

Then they must have given you broken code, since -- as I have described above -- this isn't legal code without some code changes.

Comment: The problem with `struct Date { ... Date;` is that it *isn't* invalid C++. Prof needs to stop teaching C in C++ class

Comment: Oh I absolutely agree. However OP has not actually clarified whether the `Date` struct was given _with a `Date` instance named `Date`_ or whether this their own addition. If the Prof gave a function of the form `void readDate(Date *d)`, my assumption is that OP added the `Date` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite `"struct Date {...} Date"` to something like

```
typedef struct _Date
{
...
} Date;

...

Date date;
```

Comment: Since this question is tagged C++, if OP is able to modify the `struct Date` definition, it'd be better to remove the `Date` instance from being constructed than it would to change this to a `typedef`. The `typedef struct...` approach is a C-style pattern that doesn't serve any purpose in C++, since all type identifiers always get added to the enclosing namespace (in C, `typedef struct ...` is needed to bring identifiers from the tag namespace to the identifier namespace).